# Does the sequence $x_{n+1}=2\sqrt{x_n}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-writing, proof-explanation

> Does the sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ with $x_{n+1}=2\sqrt{x_n}$ converge?

I'm almost positive this converges but I am not entirely sure how to go about this. The square root is really throwing me off as I haven't dealt with it at all up until now.

Comment: Have you tried showing that this sequence is monotone and bounded?

Comment: no I haven't how would I start something like that out?

Comment: Is anything known about $a_1$ or is it arbitrary? Have you tried using induction?

Comment: completely arbitrary and I'm absolutely horrible at induction so I haven't even tried to use that. I've been trying to see if there are any theoreoms I could abuse

Comment: I'm assuming $a_1\geq0$ anyways, pick a few random starting values and compute a few terms of the sequence, that should give you an idea on the monotonicity of your sequence, you can then try prove it by induction, pick a bound and verify your choice by inductionm, the result will follow from the Monotone Convergence Theorem

Comment: From trying a few random values, your sequence seems to be strictly increasing for $a_1<2$ and strictly decreasing for $a_1>2$

Comment: cool thanks! @pureundersgrad

Comment: The map $x\mapsto 2\sqrt x$ is a contraction map on $[1,\infty)$ with the fixed point $x=4$. If seed is in $(0,1)$, note that the map is increasing with $x\lt 2\sqrt x$, so the sequence eventually reaches 1 and the previous argument applies. The trivial case is the seed $x_0=0$ with the constant zero sequence.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
x_{n + 1} & = 2\root{x_{n}} = 2\, x_{n}^{1/2} = 2^{1 + 1/2}\,x_{n - 1}^{1/2^{2}} =
2^{1 + 1/2 + 1/2^{2}}\, x_{n - 2}^{1/2^{3}} = \cdots =
2^{\large\sum_{k = 0}^{n}2^{-k}}\,x_{0}^{1/2^{\large n + 1}}
\\[5mm] & =2^{2 - 2^{-n}}\,x_{0}^{1/2^{\large n + 1}}
\,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\Large\to}\,\,\, 2^{2} = \bbx{4}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

First, find the limit.

Suppose the sequence has a limit L.
Then $L=2\sqrt{L}$,
so $L=4$.
Note: this does not show
that the limit exists.
It shows that if the limit does exist then it must be 4.

Then, see how the limit is approached.

If
$y=2\sqrt{x}$,
then
$y-4=2\sqrt{x}-4
=2(\sqrt{x}-2)
$
so
$\frac{y-4}{x-4}
=\frac{2(\sqrt{x}-2)}{x-4}
=\frac{2(\sqrt{x}-2)}{(\sqrt{x}-2)(\sqrt{x}+2)}
=\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}+2}
$.

Therefore
$|\frac{y-4}{x-4}| < 1$
so the iterations converge
to the limit.

Comment: That's not even nearly rigorous enough. Another solution to $L$ is $0$.

Comment: @ProtectedSource Which is obtainable only if the first term is $0$.